# Adding to PS1 in bash_profile

Tags: bash, prompt, bashrc

In my `.bash_profile` currently, I have `PS1='\[\e[1;91m\][\u@\h \w]\$\[\e[0m\] '`. I am trying to follow these [commands](http://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/add-git-branch-name-to-terminal-prompt-mac) to show branch name on iTerm terminal.

I changed my

```
PS1='\[\e[1;91m\][\u@\h \w]\[\e[0m\][\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]$'
```

and the method at the end of the file

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
```

which shows now as:

```
[ava@GM12673 ~/blog][$(parse_git_branch) $
```

How to correctly add something to `PS1`?

Comment: Set your prompt in `.bashrc`, not `.bash_profile`. See [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile)

Comment: Now the coloring is gone and it still does not show the branch name.

Comment: iTerm 2 opens new shells as login shells by default, so bash reads `~/.bash_profile` but not `~/.bashrc`. I have told iTerm 2 to open new shells as non-login shells though, and I also source `~/.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quoting is broken. Change it to

```
PS1='\[\e[1;91m\][\u@\h \w]\[\e[0m\]\[\e[32m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[00m\]$'
```

Comment: It now shows as `[ava@GM12673 ~/blog][$` with no branch name. Why is an extra `[` printing?

Comment: @Ava Typo, and wrong quoting.

Comment: Now `[ava@GM12673 ~/blog][32m$`

Comment: @Ava Ah, I made a typo when correcting the typo. If this doesn't work for you, you're using some non-default bash options. Post your `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`.

Comment: Works now :) Can you also point me to a doc where it explains everything about PS1 and how to add to it?

Comment: @Ava Not exactly what you asked for, but here is a nice PS1 generator: http://xta.github.io/HalloweenBash/ Gilles, thx for fixing my answer!

Answer (score 2):

I use the parse_git_branch function myself and I've found the following works well and gives me lots of info (and a carriage return!):

```
parse_git_branch () {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'
}
PS1='\033[01;31m\]\t\033[00m\]:'
PS1=$PS1'\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:'
PS1=$PS1'\[\033[01;34m\]\w\033[00m\]:\033[01;33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
PS2='\[\033[01;36m\]>'
```

for

[image]